# CakePHP - Using A Database To Build Results For A Pull Down List In A Form

Tags: php, cakephp

What I am trying to do is use the Form Helper to build a selection pull down menu with options . These options are built from my database. There is over 100 entries in this table. Below is the line of code I use for the find command.

```
$company = $this->Company->find('list');
```

This is what I am doing to built it now, but all this does is display one result not all 100.

```
    foreach ($company as $c=>$value) { $test = $value; }

      $tmp = $this->Form->input('Client', array('options' => array($test)));
```

However, if I do this,

```
   foreach ($company as $c=>$value) { $test = $value; 

      $tmp = $this->Form->input('Client', array('options' => array($test)));
   }
```

This then prints/echos all the results. But each of them is in its own pull down menu, so I have over 100 pull down menus all over my screen. I assume this is because the foreach loop, loops around again and again printing each record until its done them all.

So how can I get this to display only one pull down with all my results/records in it?

I have look at a number of different posts on here and there are a lot of ways to do this but I can't seem to get any of them to work!

I have opened the form OK, and have already built a pull down list but with an array listed inside that PHP file, so that was easy and works!

Please help?

Thanks Glenn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$this->Form->input('Client', array('options' => array($test)));
```

to

```
$this->Form->input('Client', array('options' => array($company)));
```

Since you are getting list from database which would be in format:

```
array(
 key => value
)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Using this means I do not even need the foreach loop, I take it (just so I understand) that my $company var is just using the find command passed to it from the controller? My understanding of Cake is still limited. But many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Form->input('Client', array('options' => array($company)));
```

You Can directly use that array.It will work